# How to refresh system tray icons from a C++ code?

Tags: c++, winapi, system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you send a signal to Windows Explorer to make it refresh the systray icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723/can-you-send-a-signal-to-windows-explorer-to-make-it-refresh-the-systray-icons)

During un-installation, when the app crashes, if it had a system tray icon, the icon remains on the system tray and is not removed along with the crashed process. Is there a way to refresh system tray from a C++ code to remove this artifact?

PS. I'm not the one who wrote the app that crashes, so I cannot fix that.

Comment: Does the icon not go away when you hover the mouse over it?

Comment: You reminded me of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/14/10339263.aspx).

Comment: What I'm referring to is the area next to the clock on the taskbar. I'm also talking about doing it programmatically.

Comment: @user843732 I ask because if mouse over doesn't make the icon go away then it wasn't a clean crash (oxymoron?) and there is a process keeping the icon alive.

Comment: The taskbar notification area has very little controlling API as most of the other areas do. I don't think it's possible to refresh the area, at least not with documented methods.

Comment: @TheZ: Yes, it does go away if I mouse over it...

Comment: take a look at the similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723/can-you-send-a-signal-to-windows-explorer-to-make-it-refresh-the-systray-icons)

Comment: @Apokal: Very nice find. Thank you!