# Removing NotifyIcon from the notification area

Tags: windows, delphi, components, system-tray, trayicon

Is it possible to remove  `NotifyIcon` from the notification area (system tray) when an app terminates abruptly?

if no, how can I remove it when the app runs for the next time?

Comment: Please define "terminates abruptly".

Comment: When the app crashes or unexpectedly shuts down.

Comment: In those situations you still have the opportunity to remove the notification icon gracefully. I assume you are using try/finally properly. It's really just forceful termination (TerminateProcess) that you cannot defend against.

Comment: There's this, but it's not in Delphi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723/can-you-send-a-signal-to-windows-explorer-to-make-it-refresh-the-systray-icons

Comment: In fact, I had never thought of it before, but seeing your user name made me realise it: Delphi is actually the gradient of a typical scalar field.

Comment: Good find, @Marcus. Doesn't matter if it's not Delphi. The Windows API is the same in any language.

Answer (score 5):

Abruptly? No. Your program has ceased to exist, so there's no opportunity to run any code to tell the shell that it should remove the icon.

To remove the icon, move your mouse over it. The shell will try to notify your program, realize there's nothing there anymore, and remove the icon by itself.

Comment: I know that is just the Way Windows behaves when an app with a tray icon crashes. But I want to remove it when the app runs for the next time.

Comment: @DelPhi, you could write down previous icon params and attempt to `NIM_DELETE` on startup.

Comment: I'm using try/finally and this command {Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @IconData);}.

Comment: @DelPhi If you want to remove it, then do so. You have to do that from the application that created the icon.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I can't figure out if it's created already. That command only removes the running IconData

Comment: No! I mean that if your application crashes, remove the icon before the process terminates. In other words, don't get into that state in the first place. There's probably just an error in your code. Fix the real problem rather than the symptoms

Comment: @David Heffernan, I've tried to remove it on destroy form and it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest that you describe the problem better than "it didn't work". Is the form not being destroyed? Is the code to delete the icon broken?

Comment: It didn't work, because the app has been terminated without calling destroy().

Comment: @DelPhi Then that's the thing to fix.

Comment: Nothing helpful in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7 and later, notify icons can be identified by a user-defined GUID.  On earlier versions, they are identified by a combination of HWND and ID number instead.  Since your app is not guaranteed to get the same HWND value the next time it runs, the only way you can do anything to an old icon that is identified by HWND is if you remembered the previous HWND value so you can use it to remove the old icon, before then using a new HWND to add a new icon.  But with a GUID-identified icon, the GUID needs to be persistent (as it is stored in the Registry to store app settings associated with the icon), so you should be able to simply keep updating the existing icon as needed, or remove it if desired.

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation whether that GUID really identifies a single icon, or just a single *type* of icon. That is, if multiple instances of a program run simultaneously, must they all use distinct GUIDs for their icons? Or is it just that an instance that shows multiple icons must use a different GUID for each icon? I would expect the latter since the former would be difficult to implement. And if that's true, then a later instance of the program would still be unable to clean up the icon of the previous crashed instance.

Comment: The docs suggest that the guid uniquely identifies a particular icon for a given copy of the app's executable, not for a given process of the app like with the HWND+ID combo. The docs do say that multiple icons in an app need to use separate guids. Also that the guids are stored in the Registry and it stores the app's full path with each guid, so side-by-side installations must use different guids for the same icon in each installation. If the app moves to a new path, the guids(s) of the old path must be unregistered so the new path can then be associated with the guid(s).

Comment: So under those conditions, it does sound like a later instance of the app process can take control of a previous app process's icons, since they are not tied to any given process when identified by a guid.  But I may be wrong.  I still use the HWND+ID combo in my apps, they haven't been updated to use guids yet.

Comment: I just ran a test. On Win7 with one icon identified by guid, running multiple instances of that app, only one copy of the icon showed up in the system tray. So that does suggest one icon instance per guid, and multiple app instances can share that one icon instance.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, since code doesn't exist so far, I thought I'd throw this in.  I don't know if it will help or not for the OP, but it should be good guidance in the right direction.

```
unit csystray;
  { removes dead system tray icons, by Glenn1234 @ stackoverflow.com
    since this uses "less than supported by Microsoft" means, it may
    not work on all operating system.  It was tested on Windows XP }
interface
  uses commCtrl, shellapi, windows;
type
  TTrayInfo = packed record
    hWnd: HWnd;
    uID: UINT;
    uCallBackMessage: UINT;
    Reserved1: array[0..1] of longint;
    Reserved2: array[0..2] of longint;
    hIcon: HICON;
  end;
  PTBButton = ^TTBButton;
  _TBBUTTON = packed record
    iBitmap: Integer;
    idCommand: Integer;
    fsState: Byte;
    fsStyle: Byte;
    bReserved: array[1..2] of Byte;
    dwData: Longint;
    iString: Integer;
  end;
  TTBButton = _TBBUTTON;

procedure RemoveStaleTrayIcons;

implementation

procedure RemoveStaleTrayIcons;
const
  VMFLAGS = PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_READ OR PROCESS_VM_WRITE;
var
  ProcessID: THandle;
  ProcessHandle: THandle;
  trayhandle: HWnd;
  ExplorerButtonInfo: Pointer;
  i: integer;
  ButtonCount: Longint;
  BytesRead: Longint;
  ButtonInfo: TTBButton;
  TrayInfo: TTrayInfo;
  ClassNameA: Array[0..255] of char;
  outlen: integer;
  TrayIconData: TNotifyIconData;
begin
  // walk down the window hierarchy to find the notification area window
  trayhandle := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', '');
  trayhandle := FindWindowEx(trayhandle, 0, 'TrayNotifyWnd', nil);
  trayhandle := FindWindowEx(trayhandle, 0, 'SysPager', nil);
  trayhandle := FindWindowEx(trayhandle, 0, 'ToolbarWindow32', nil);
  if trayhandle = 0 then exit;
  // find the notification area process and open it up for reading.
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(trayhandle, @ProcessID);
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(VMFLAGS, false, ProcessID);
  ExplorerButtonInfo := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessHandle, nil, Sizeof(TTBButton),
       MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
  // the notification area is a tool bar.  Get the number of buttons.
  ButtonCount := SendMessage(trayhandle, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);
  if ExplorerButtonInfo <> nil then
    try
      // iterate the buttons & check.
      for i := (ButtonCount - 1) downto 0 do
        begin
          // get button information.
          SendMessage(trayhandle, TB_GETBUTTON, i, LParam(ExplorerButtonInfo));
          ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, ExplorerButtonInfo, @ButtonInfo,
             Sizeof(TTBButton), BytesRead);
          // if there's tray data, read and process
          if Buttoninfo.dwData <> 0 then
            begin
              ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, PChar(ButtonInfo.dwData),
                                @TrayInfo, Sizeof(TTrayInfo), BytesRead);
              // here's the validation test, this fails if the master window is invalid
              outlen := GetClassName(TrayInfo.hWnd, ClassNameA, 256);
              if outlen < 1 then
                begin
                  // duplicate the shell icon removal, i.e. my component's DeleteTray
                  TrayIconData.cbSize := sizeof(TrayIconData);
                  TrayIconData.Wnd := TrayInfo.hWnd;
                  TrayiconData.uID := TrayInfo.uID;
                  TrayIconData.uCallbackMessage := TrayInfo.uCallBackMessage;
                  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, @TrayIconData);
                end;
            end;
        end;
    finally
      VirtualFreeEx(ProcessID, ExplorerButtonInfo, Sizeof(TTBButton), MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that digging into another process's memory to fetch undocumented information is ever really "guidance in the right direction."